# Github API rate limit specifics

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to find some specific details on the GitHub API rate limit.
I have seen many different places suggesting 5000 requests per hour, but I have been limited to 30 according to my [response headers](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#rate-limiting).
I have looked at a couple other questions related to GitHub rate limits but haven't found any specifics on them.

I authenticate my requests with [OAUTH in the headers](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#oauth2-token-sent-in-a-header).

I receive:

> Error: Request failed with status code 403

which according to the docs means I'm authenticated.

What I would like to know is:

- What are the different rate limits?
- Why would I receive 30/hour while someone else may have 5000/hour?
- How do I increase it?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely seeing a reduced rate limit because you are not *successfully* authenticating.  You may be providing credentials, but those credentials are not correct, don't have the right scopes, or are otherwise not valid for the resources you're requesting.  If you're accessing public information, then you'd get access to that data anyway even without authenticating, so your invalid credentials wouldn't matter but would result in a reduced rate limit.

The reason GitHub provides different rate limits for authenticated and unauthenticated users is to prevent abuse and make it possible to contact users who are engaging in excessive or unacceptable behaviors.  For example, if a bot account or OAuth app is causing problems, the maintainer of that service can be contacted, and in an emergency, that account can be prevented from accessing the API until it can be fixed so as not to impact other users.

You can, as the documentation mentions, get an increased rate limit for the API by successfully authenticating.  You haven't provided any details about what you're requesting or what scopes you've asked for, so we can't help there; you'll probably want to ask another question with more details.  Beyond the limit of 5000 requests, you'd have to ask GitHub Support, although that is a relatively generous limit.

Comment: I would say there is no chance I'm not authenticating, as I am still receiving data from private repos inside a private organization from my requests. As you say I may need to make a new question with details specific to my request.

Comment: GitHub provides the rate limits specified in its documentation (or, in special cases, higher ones).  If you're getting lower values from the headers, then that means you've either exhausted them (e.g., with many REST requests or complex GraphQL ones), or there's something about your authentication that's preventing it from taking effect to give you the higher limits.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed if you create multiple accounts from the same IP those new accounts will have a lower rate limit of 60 and not 5000. If you create accounts by using a different IP via a VPN or something like that then the rate limit is 5000. They are discouraging this though so I would be careful.